# Can I enter Israel with new passport and valid visa on the old passport?

Tags: israel, passport-renewals

I have a plan to visit Israel on 15/12.
Unfortunately, My passport which is used for visa applied, was out of page, So I have to have a new one.
Could I use the current visa to enter your country. I can bring both old and new passport for checking at the immigration dpt.

Comment: yes. there are about 500000 duplicates of this question here.

Comment: @Aganju, also for Israel? If so, post a link.

Comment: the answers will be valid for all countries AFAIK it is an international law.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Which International Law would that be? It is certainly not part of the Passport Conventions that define common Passport and Visa procedures.

Comment: No way this is international, for example in China this would be heavily dependent on the city and the immigrations officer at thats time

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience, yes you can do this. Just present both passports to the immigration official and note that you have a visa in the old one.